# Where are the numerical release version numbers for Azure DevOps Server found (before install)?

Tags: version, azure-devops-server-2019

I am looking to patch my current install of Azure DevOps Server and have been looking for the numerical release version of the different patches/installs for Azure DevOps Server so I can determine the new changes that are coming through (or if a patch is even needed). All I can find (and feeling pretty stupid for it) are the names of each the installs/patches such as 'Azure DevOps Server 2019 Patch 1 Release Date: April 9, 2019' or the latest version, 'Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 Patch 2 Release Date: April 14, 2020'.

My current installation is *17.153.29207.5 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1)* which I found in the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console. I can speculate that *Update1* might refer to the release, 'Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 Release Date: August 20, 2019' but realistically, *Update* could have many different interpretations.I was hoping to find the actual version number to guarrantee which version I am actually upgrading to.

Does any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the installation file (.exe), then check details of that file: Right click the file > Properties > Details > Check Product version.

This article may benefit you: [Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019u1?view=azure-devops)